# idangerous slider styling peek preview for prev/next

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm trying to use the iDangerous Slider to show some images from a gallery. The idea is to view the active item in the center and the prev/next item should peek out left and right.

For a better understanding i attached an image.

[image]

I was unable to set some kind of viewport. I hope you can help me.

For easier testing, i set up a Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rxmkjx1e/3/

**EDIT**

I figured out that `slidesPerView: 2` produces a really near solution. But how can i variegate the width of the visible part of the prev/next image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a pretty solution

Wrapping the Slider into a viewport

```
<div class="viewport">
[SLIDER]
</div>
```

Some styling

```
.viewport {
    display: block;
    width:80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Take a look into the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/rxmkjx1e/4/